# Simple javascript to know which cell in table cell clicked

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm writing a Sudoku html page and just want to know what table cell was clicked. It's proving quite difficult. The table is just:

```html
<table id="sudoku">
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

Each cell has an event listener like this:

```
addEventListener('click', pickSquare);

function pickSquare() {
    // clear old selection
    prev_selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");

    for (i = 0; i < prev_selected.length; i++)  {
        prev_selected[i].className = prev_selected[i].className.replace(" selected", "");
    }

    this.className += " selected";
    editing = this;
}
```

This gives me access to the cell so I can change the value etc but my difficulty is working out the cell number so I can add some addition logic. I'd like to do it in JavaScript as that's what I'm trying to teach myself at the moment.

Comment: Table cells have a `cellIndex` property, and table row elements have `rowIndex`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex

Comment: Consider using the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) interface rather than manually manipulating `className`.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("selected")` is bug prone, tomorrow it could be any element in the DOM, just not the one you expected.

Comment: How should I implement selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JS events bubble up to parent elements, you can use a single event listener on the `table` element and access the `event.target` property to find the element that was clicked. Then we can use `element.cellIndex` and `element.parentElement.rowIndex` to find our X and Y coordinates in the `table`.

```js
document.querySelector('#sudoku')
  .addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    const [x, y] = [
      ev.target.cellIndex, 
      ev.target.parentElement.rowIndex
    ];
    if (x === undefined || y === undefined) {
      // Clicked on space between cells
      return;
    }
    console.log(x, y);
  });
```

```html
<table id="sudoku">
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```